# To what features a plugin belongs

Tags: eclipse, rcp

When am trying to export a product based on features things could be a lot easier if a could explore in the target platform the herarchy of features and the plugins they contain, some "features references" action in the context menu of a plugin. I don't undertand how something so fundamental as this is so painful to do, currently I:

- use a mix of find and grep in the features folder to search for
  plugins which could contain the plugin
- or use the features location in the target platform with show contents checked.

Is there other ways of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any plugin can be included in multiple features. i.e The `feature` is the container of set(group) of plugins.

You can use search dialog to find the all features in which the current plugin was included.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>. Enter the details as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this will only scan the workspace not the features in my target. I created a new general project and import the features folder available in every target location I have configured for my target. Thank you thank you thank you!